# how to get path of specific bufferedimage?

Tags: java, image, swing, stack

Hi I am trying to get path of BufferedImage but how to get path of that loaded image i don't know.
I am fetching image from Stack<>. one by one image fetched from it when user click on next button.
image changed using pop() method of stack.

code :

```
        Stack<File> pictures ;
        final JFileChooser file;
        file = new JFileChooser();
        file.setCurrentDirectory(dir);
        file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        file.showOpenDialog(panel);
        String path = file.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(path);
        pictures= getFilesInFolder(path.toString());    


        a=ImageIO.read(pictures.pop().getAbsoluteFile());
```

here `a` is Buffered Image instance.
now i want whole path of image that loaded in `a`.

anyone guide me ?

Comment: Hava you added a File to the Stack or a BufferedImage?

Comment: yes i have added and this concept taught by you to me.

Comment: Just use stack.peek() before you use a pop. peek shows you the first image of the stack. So: `stack.peek().getAbsuluthPath();` or not?

Comment: sir each time i want full path with image name in one string variable. but how to do that i am just confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `BufferedImage` does not maintain any information on how it is generated or where it is loaded from. You have to store the file path in a variable before loading the image:

```
    File file = pictures.pop().getAbsoluteFile();
    a=ImageIO.read(file);
    // now you can use "file" for other purposes too
```

Comment: suppose i want to store path of that in string variable then how should i do ??

Comment: @user2659972 or do it like so. Now you are able to use file.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: `String path = file.getPath();` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getPath%28%29

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is that you have is that you can't read a Path from a BufferedImage so you have to use the File before you make a BufferedImage of it.

So you could use:

```
String path = stack.peek().getPath();
```

Now you have saved your path. At the moment you convert it into a BufferedImage use `pop()` so you remove it from the stack. With `peek()` you only look at the first Item **without removing**. Or you save your file into a temp file like

```
File temp = stack.pop();
```

Than you are able to use:

```
temp.getPath();
```

Comment: sir i have made that, i have sent you one file to scale image but you don't reply. my whole application is ready i just have to scale image but i am not getting it.

Comment: Did it work!? ^^ Yea could be I am sorry but that email I gave you is actully a fake mail or better to say a mail to keep my identity. I don't look at this so I havent seen it.

Comment: @user2659972 I will have a look at it on stackoverflow. If I know a solution I will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

yes i have solve that using following code :

```
            String p;
            File f;
            try 
            {
                f= pictures.pop().getAbsoluteFile();
                a=ImageIO.read(f);
                p = f.getPath();
                System.out.println(p);


            } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```